# JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I wish to create a JSON object that is derived from the selected options of 4 select menus. These menus may have options selected when loaded (due to a server side technology) or may have no options selected whatsoever! Once the page is loaded using $(document).ready() my script runs… however I’m getting some problems with the JSON object “**JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data**”

I want my JSON to have the following structure

```
selObj = {

    category: selectedCategory, // we can only have 1 category, this isn’t giving me a problem…

    catOptions:{
        optionValue:discountValue, // we can have many of these
        optionValue:discountValue,
        optionValue:discountValue
    },

    tariff:{
        tariffValue:discountValue, // we can have many of these
        tariffValue:discountValue
    },

    tarOptions:{
        tarOption:discountValue, // we can have many of these

    }

};
```

Okay here’s my function, I’ve removed some items here to simplify, but I’m passing an original empty object into the function as an argument and then hoping to amend this as I will want to pass the JSON object back to the server if/when the select menus are changed… but for now we’re just dealing with the page loading… the function also shows the values or what is selected in a dynamic table that is created using a function called `defaultTable()` just ignore that for now, it’s the populating of the JSON object I’m interested in (and having problems with).

```
var selectMenuArray = ["cat", "catOpt", "tariff", "tariffOpt"], // these are the IDs of the select menus...     
selObj = {};

function setUpTable(selectArray, theObj){

    // okay, if we enter the page and and the user already has a tarif selected (so it is shown in the menus) we wish to show the table with the 
    // default/original values...

    var currentSelect,
        catA = [],
        catOptA = [],
        tarA = [],
        tarOptA  = [],
        catOptForObj,
        tariffForObj,
        tariffOptForObj,
        temp1 = {},
        temp2 = {},
        temp3 = {},
        i;

    // loop through the 4 menus and see what is selected
    for(i=0;i<selectArray.length;i++){
    // let's look at the options to see if any are selected by looping through the <option>
        currentSelect = document.getElementById(selectArray[i]);

        for(j=0;j<currentSelect.length;j++){
            // do we have an options with the selected attribute?
            if(currentSelect.options[j].selected == true){
                // okay, we need to make sure the table is shown then the correct values are shown?
                // we know what the Menu is... selectArray[i], and this is the text... currentSelect.options[j].
                // lets build up whet's selected in Arrays...
                switch(selectArray[i]){
                    case "cat":
                        catA.push(currentSelect.options[j].value);
                        break;
                    case "catOpt":          
                        catOptA.push(currentSelect.options[j].value);
                        catOptForObj = catOptForObj + '"' + currentSelect.options[j].value + '":"' + "% to come later" + '",';
                        break;
                    case "tariff":
                        tarA.push(currentSelect.options[j].value);
                        tariffForObj = tariffForObj + '"' + currentSelect.options[j].value + '":"' + "% to come later" + '",';
                        break;  
                    case "tariffOpt":
                        tarOptA.push(currentSelect.options[j].value);
                        tariffOptForObj = tariffOptForObj + '"' + currentSelect.options[j].value + '":"' + "% to come later" + '",';
                        break;  
                    default:
                    // no default?
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // now we can build the table
    if(catA.length > 0 || catOptA.length > 0 || tarA.length > 0 || tarOptA.length > 0){

        // show table...
        $("#dynamicTableHolder table").css("visibility","visible").hide().fadeIn('slow');

        for(i=0;i<selectArray.length;i++){  
            switch(selectArray[i]){ 
                case "cat":
                    defaultTable(catA, "dtCats");
                    theObj.cat = catA[0];
                    break;
                case "catOpt":          
                    defaultTable(catOptA, "dtTariffs");
                    temp1 = '"{' + catOptForObj.substring(0, catOptForObj.length-1).replace(/undefined/g, "")  + '}"'; 
                    theObj = jQuery.parseJSON('"catOptions":' + temp1);
                    break;
                case "tariff":
                    defaultTable(tarA, "dtCatOpts");
                    temp2 = "{" + tariffForObj.substring(0, tariffForObj.length-1).replace(/undefined/g, "") + "}";
                    //theObj = jQuery.parseJSON('"tariff":' + temp2);
                    break;  
                case "tariffOpt":
                    defaultTable(tarOptA, "dtTariffOpts");
                    temp3 = "{" + tariffOptForObj.substring(0, tariffOptForObj.length-1).replace(/undefined/g, "") + "}";
                    //theObj = jQuery.parseJSON('"tarOptions":' + temp3);
                    break;  
                default:
                // no default?
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I’m having problems with making the JSON object, what I’m trying to do is concatenate strings whilst looping, then covert these to objects using the jQuery.parseJSON method… however I’m not doing this correctly. I’ve even tried changing the quotation marks when creating temp1.

I know this is complicated and I may be asking a lot but can anyone see what I’m doing wrong. I’m not that familiar with jQuery.parseJSON so any advice would be great as I think I’m going mad!

If I'm being vague or not explaining myself well please say so... I've also put this on fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/itakesmack/JSRt7/1/

PLEASE NOTE THIS IS A WORKING PROGRESS SO SOME ITEMS MAY BE MISSING OR NEED TO BE DEVELOPED (or I may have other bugs... but I hope not).

Comment: NEVER build JSON using string functions. Use `JSON.stringify()` on a proper object.

Comment: Also remember not to add actual comments in your JSON as though it is JavaScript; JSON does not allow them (unless you include them as part of the object)

Comment: Cheers for that, I'll make sure not to comment... I'm finding all of this confusing... but I will prevail!

Comment: How exactly should I use JSON.stringify() in the function... I'm still getting the same problem?

Comment: i checked out your fiddle...the code was extremely complicated...you should have spent some more time on designing it. Anyways, there's a problem - you setup your selObj when the page loads, but when you change the selections, you aren't updating the object -- is that what you actually want to do? if so, then there's no point of all this right?

Comment: can you please explain what are you doing with all those variables in the setupTable function?

Comment: @MikeSav: go to https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js and download the json2.js and include it in your head scripts.  usage is JSON.stringify(<object or array>)...

Comment: Furthering what ThiefMaster said, instead of trying to build this up with strings, you'd be better off doing something like `var myObj = {}; myObj["val1"] = currentSelect.options[1]` -- that is, create a proper object from the get go.

Answer (score 3):

You're feeding parseJSON() a string that looks like `'"catOptions":"{"A":"B","C":"D",}"'`
parseJSON() wants something that looks like this  `'{"catOptions":{"A":"B","C":"D"}}'`

You've got a few problems to deal with if you are going to build the JSON by hand.

To fix your error you don't want to wrap your `{key:value}` in quotes, they are being broken by the quotes inside catOptForObj

You'll need to escape values you are building OptForObj strings with if they may contain double quotes

You are basically building your string like this:

```
s = s + '"' + A '":"' + "B" + '",';
```

which will produce something like `"A":"B","C":"D",`

Commas should only exists between values. One way to do this is check to see if s is empty first, and only append it to s before your additional value. Something like:

```
s = (s.length?(s+','):'') + '"' + A + '":"' + "B" + '"';
```

What would be best is to rely on a built in function like JSON.stringify as suggested in the comments

Answer (score 0):

To add values to a JSON object you are using string.

```
catOptForObj = catOptForObj + '"' + currentSelect.options[j].value + '":"' + "% to come later" + '",';
```

Instead you can try the following convention to assign values to the different keys in JSON.

`catOptForObj[currentSelect.options[j].value] = "% to come later";`